# "eval is evil()" - But can it be a way around some of the limitations of Minimal Download Strategy?

Tags: javascript, master-page, minimal-download-strategy, evaluation

The process of getting custom JavaScript to work with *Minimal Download Strategy* is quite cumbersome and especially in the prototyping phase I like to write my (smaller) scripts inline in a *Content* or *Script Editor Webpart*. As we all know, this won't be very successful when *MDS* is activated.

I added a little piece of code to my development environment *Masterpage*:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery("#DeltaPlaceHolderMain script.MDSeval")
    .not("div.ms-rtestate-field script.MDSeval")
    .each(function(){
        //console.debug("Attempting to eval() Script")
        //console.debug(this)
        eval(jQuery(this).text())
    })
},0)
```

As you can see it will look for <script>-tags with class 'MDSeval' in *#DeltaPlaceHolderMain* and evaluates them, and that's actually working pretty nice. And even though <script>-tags are not allowed in RTE fields, I have another check just to make sure.

Now I'm wondering how this would fare in a production environment.
Do you see any major or potential problems with this approach?
Are there still ways left a user could use to smuggle in malicious code even though he has no permission to design pages?

Comment: Something like this: https://sharepointannoyances.wordpress.com/2014/04/09/loading-javascript-via-customaction-and-initializing-functions-with-sharepoint-2013s-minimal-download-strategy/

Comment: That comment is totally unrelated to my question.

Comment: I thought you were looking for a better way to check for MDS without having to run an eval, this shows how to check for MDS and act accordingly.

Comment: No problem whatsoever to run scripts with MDS. But the process (for example as described in the blog post you posted) is what I would call cumbersome. So my question is: instead of going though this process, how about just eval() tiny inline scripts? What are the concerns? Are there any? Are there still ways that users smuggle in malicious code? Not talking about massive scripts here, but those tiny "please make a slideDown animation for this list"-requests. Would be way easier just to be able to do it inline than to add a custom action etc..

Comment: Alrighty, I misunderstood what you were getting at.

Answer (score 0):

Eval is Evil

Oh My! Then you have to stop using SharePoint; as its code uses `eval()` in several places:

`sp.js` uses it once:

```
   $v_0.MenuItems = eval($p1.get_executor().get_responseData());
```

`core.js` ... uses it **20** times !!!

I will let you explore the other 15+ JavaScript libraries SharePoint loads into your browser yourself.

The phrase Eval is Evil is about its ability to execute JavaScript from a String...
So if you let users enter a String and pass it to `eval()`

You **COULD** be in deep shit... it is all up to you as a developer.

Note: JavaScript **Client-Side** users can do whatever they want, it's server-side code where the 'issues' with Eval occur

Among real JavaScript developers the phrase `Eval is Evil` is at the same level as Godwin's Law or Scopie's Law

> If someone refers to Eval is Evil, he/she does not understand JavaScript <period>

Comment: Yep, that's why I put it into quotation marks. It's not my own oppinion and I know that it is used approx. 200 times throughout SharePoints JS codebase. My question is aimed at whether there are any potentially bad side effects of the way I use it in the snippet above. I don't want to start a general discussion about eval() itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hook into MDS you might want use the official way with the  **asyncDeltaManager**

- https://www.spcaf.com/blog/sharepoint-javascript-context-development-part-4-the-way-of-the-async-delta-manager/
  Is a bit complex but has all the info
- http://blog.symprogress.com/2013/09/sharepoint-2013-execute-javascript-function-after-mds-load/
  Is a good starter

There are all kind of MDS events like:

```
asyncDeltaManager.add_beginRequest( function(){} );
asyncDeltaManager.add_pageLoaded( function(){} );
asyncDeltaManager.add_endRequest( function(){} );
```